# First SSH connection reset by peer, subsequent ones work

Tags: ssh, firewall, linux-networking

I am facing a fairly odd issue on a new VPS:

Whenever I initiate an SSH connection to the server for the first time in a while, I get this:

```
➜  ~ ssh server
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by XXX port 22
```

The next attempt will immediately work. The following attempts will work, until some time has passed, where the next connection results in a "Connection reset by peer" again. The problem reproduces systematically.

In the system logs, I see this at the time of the initial failed connection:

```
Jan 25 00:07:13  kernel: cni0: port 29(veth15fb1b36) entered disabled state
Jan 25 00:07:13  kernel: device veth15fb1b36 left promiscuous mode
Jan 25 00:07:13  kernel: cni0: port 29(veth15fb1b36) entered disabled state
```

The other log lines seem irrelevant, and none contain the IP of the client machine.

Right after on the second successful attempt:

```
Jan 25 00:08:43  sshd[1529804]: Accepted publickey for root from CLIENT_IP
Jan 25 00:08:43  sshd[1529804]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
```

A bit before the failure:

```
Jan 25 00:05:00  kernel: cni0: port 29(veth15fb1b36) entered blocking state
Jan 25 00:05:00  kernel: cni0: port 29(veth15fb1b36) entered disabled state
Jan 25 00:05:00  kernel: device veth15fb1b36 entered promiscuous mode
Jan 25 00:05:00  kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jan 25 00:05:00  kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth15fb1b36: link becomes ready
Jan 25 00:05:00  kernel: cni0: port 29(veth15fb1b36) entered blocking state
Jan 25 00:05:00  kernel: cni0: port 29(veth15fb1b36) entered forwarding state
```

The server has a plain Debian 12 installation, with ufw configured, as well as a k3s installation.

I think that the cni0/veth logs are coming from k3s, so maybe they are unrelated.

It's as if there was a port-knocking firewall, but I don't see anything like that installed or in the logs. Would anyone have an idea about what could be happening?

Comment: Can you please enable verbose logging for ssh, and maybe let ssh listen on eth0 fixed. Also provide your current sshd config using `sshd -T`. It looks like for some reason the interfaces are going up and down